# Save model forms in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

This is supposed to be a trial run of a sign up form but the database is not storing the username and password. The error I'm getting is "The User could not be created because the data didn't validate".

views.py

```
def add_model(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            model_instance=form.save(commit=False)
            model_instance.save()
```

forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['username','password']
```

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key=True,default="")
    password=models.CharField(max_length=15,default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Comment: If you only want to save the instance, you just need to save the form: `form.save()`

Comment: model_instance is just the variable name. I'm just validating the form before saving it

Comment: What I'm saying is that just doing `form.save()` after validating it, you will get the instance saved.

Comment: If I remove the form.is_valid() from my original code, it is adding the details to the database. form.is_valid() is giving me some error

Answer (score 2):

It should be `if form.is_valid()` instead of `if form.is_valid`.

And **"the data didn't validate"** basically means you are trying to `save()` an invalid form.

Comment: The validations specified in the model are met. Why is it still an invalid form?

Comment: If it's telling you "the data didn't validate", there gotta be something wrong with the data submitted. In your previous code `if form.is_valid` will always equal to `True`, and when you try to `save()` it'll tell you "the data didn't validate" if there's something wrong with the data. "The validations specified in the model are met.", I would say it's probably NOT validated, and it won't pass `form.is_valid()`

Answer (score 0):

forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['username','password']
    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')    

    def clean_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
```

views.py

```
  def add_model(request):
            if request.method=="POST":
                form=UserForm(request.POST or None)
                if form.is_valid():
                    username = form.cleaned_data['username']
                    password = form.cleaned_data['password']
                    new_user = User()
                    new_user.username = username
                    new_user.password = password
                    new_user.save()
```

I think This should be working correctly for your purpose.

Comment: No. Doesn't work. If I remove the form.is_valid() from my original code, it is adding the details to the database

Comment: If it enters the valid if condition, I redirect it to a new webpage, but it doesn't go there. Means the form.is_valid() condition is false